# Поиск в переменной bash

Tags: bash

Надо узнать MAC-адрес (eth0, например). ifconfig выдаёт помимо mac'а кучу ненужного мне мусора. Думал вычленить вывод регуляркой, но не знаю как. То что находил проверяло строку на соответствие регулярке, но не производило поиск/сохранение в массив.

Comment: Так может не из ifconfig брать, а из cat /sys/class/net/*/address?

Comment: Да, благодарю, сработало.

Answer (score 6):

хотя программа *ifconfig* [морально и физически устарела для целей управления, диагностики и получения информации](http://unixforum.org/index.php?showtopic=129712) в операционных системах, использующих программу *linux* в качестве ядра, приведу пример и для неё:

```
$ x=$(/sbin/ifconfig имя-интерфейса); x=${x#*HWaddr }; x=${x%% *}; echo $x
11:22:33:44:55:66
```

или, не «на чистом bash»:

```
$ /sbin/ifconfig имя-интерфейса | awk '/HWaddr/ {print $5}')
11:22:33:44:55:66
```

---

а с использованием актуальной программы *ip* из [пакета программ *iproute2*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iproute2) — например, так:

```
$ x=$(ip -o l sh имя интерфейса); x=${x#*ether }; x=${x%% *}; echo $x
11:22:33:44:55:66
```

---

или, если смонтирована [виртуальная файловая система *sysfs*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysfs), то ещё короче:

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/имя-интерфейса/address
11:22:33:44:55:66
```

---

подробнее про *shell parameter expansion* в программе *bash* — см. [документацию](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html).